# How to prevent links from being spammed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, captcha, spam, viber

Currently some bots are spamming on my viber link posted on my static website with no backend integration. The link is a tag as `<a href="some_viber_community_link">Join Our Viber Support</a>`.

If I create a captcha and render the button only after successful validation, will it prevent spamming?

My basic concern is the link to the viber group will be stored in a variable in react state itself as string. Can that be accessed by the bot before rendering? If it can be accessed by scrapers/bots, then I should integrate a backend to fetch the link after successful captcha validation.

Answer (score 1):

So I encrypted the link and handled decryption during onclick event. The bot is not able to read the link and my onclick works as expected

Comment: For some bots its still possible, to manually fire the click event.

Comment: Very interesting! can you provide an example or a tip of how you've achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the latest version google recaptcha. It validates the access from the begining. It's usually in my websites.

Comment: Yes i know i can use google recaptcha,, but my concern is, will scrapers/bot be able to scrape my unrendered link to the viber community?